# Comparing SQL query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following queries.

Query 1:

```
SELECT sb.number
     , sb.Trace
     , sb.Amount
     , sp.edge, sp.UserId
  FROM Budget sb JOIN SNAP sp ON sb.Trace = sp.Trace
 WHERE sb.Trace 
    IN (SELECT Trace FROM SNAP WHERE User='R5' )
 ORDER BY sp.edge DESC
```

Output:

```
number      Trace       Amount  Edge        UserId
111276509   40902337    30.00   21673074    R5
111276507   40902333    17.00   21673073    R5
111276505   40902331    29.00   21673071    R5
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT sb.number
     , sb.Trace
     , sb.Amount
     , sp.edge,sp.UserId  
  FROM Budget sb JOIN SNAP sp ON sb.Trace = sp.Trace
 WHERE sb.Trace 
    IN (SELECT Trace FROM SNAP WHERE UserId<>'R5' )
 ORDER BY sp.edge DESC
```

Output:

```
number      Trace       Amount  Edge        UserId
111276509   50902337    20.00   21673074    App
111276507   50902333    50.00   21673073    App
111276505   50902331    70.00   21673071    App
```

Now, I just need to compare the Edge column from both outputs and if the value is the same it should output corresponding records from both tables.
Eg: for Edge value 21673074 I should get

```
number      Trace       Amount  Edge        UserId
111276509   40902337    30.00   21673074    R5
111276509   50902337    20.00   21673074    App
```

Comment: use these as subqueries - then join on the common column.

Comment: Could you please let me know? I am new to sql :)

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: Copy both sets of results to text files and use something like Beyond Compare to see if they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses window functions:

```
select sbp.*
from (select sb.number, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId,
             sum(case when User = 'R5' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by trace) as num_R5,
             sum(case when User <> 'R5' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by trace) as num_NotR5
      from Budget sb join
           SNAP sp 
           on sb.Trace = sp.Trace
     ) sbp
where num_R5 > 0 and num_NotR5 > 0
order by sp.edge desc;
```

Another just builds on your queries:

```
select sb.number, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId
from Budget sb join
     SNAP sp 
     on sb.Trace = sp.Trace
where sb.Trace in (select Trace from SNAP where User = 'R5' ) and
      sb.Trace in (select Trace from SNAP where User <> 'R5' )
order by sp.edge desc;
```

Of course, one of the two `exists` is redundant, because the current row automatically  matches one of them.  You can make this more efficient as:

```
select sb.number, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId
from Budget sb join
     SNAP sp 
     on sb.Trace = sp.Trace
where (sp.User <> 'R5' and
       sb.Trace in (select Trace from SNAP where User = 'R5' )
      ) or
      (sp.User = 'R5' and
       sb.Trace in (select Trace from SNAP where User <> 'R5' )
      )
order by sp.edge desc;
```

Comment: your second query have double `sb.Trace in` i guess one is `sp` just not sure which one.

Comment: I ran all the three queries. I'm not getting any records. Can anyone please let me know